# <p:treeNode> cannot access <p:tree var="node">

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

I am trying to build a primefaces tree from database.But i couldn't manage it.
Here is my xhtml :

```
<p:tree  value="#{userBean.root}"
                             var="node"
                             selectionMode="single"
                             selection="#{userBean.selectedNode}"
                             >

                        <p:treeNode>
                            <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
                        </p:treeNode>
 </p:tree>
```

And here is bean :

```
private List<UserModel> userList;
private TreeNode root;
root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);

    for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
        TreeNode node = new DefaultTreeNode(userList.get(i) ,root);

       // node.setRowKey(userList.get(i).getMIdUser() + "");
    }
```

What i am trying to do is that i want to have both object name and its id that is why i added a object to default tree node.
But on xhtml page var name of tree is 'node'. On tree node i cannot say 'node.name'

i hope i can explain the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have posted only relevant parts of your bean and that the been has all stuff you need like getRoot() and the like. than the only thing I see is missing is the:

```
<p:tree ... dynamic="true">
```

attribute in your tree definition. the rest should work. If still not, add more code from your bean and add the IVSOSUserModel to your post.

Comment: thank you for reply.I did not implement getRoot() function.This must be implemented ?

Comment: and my main problem is : i cannot say 'node.name'

Comment: if you have no getRoot, then you have no access to #{userBean.root}. if the code you posted above is your bean - it doesn't work either. once you have a bean and you can access all fields (via public ... get...() methods) and fields are properly initialized, then your code will work. ath the moment it looks like you have done to little for it to work.